# WCF 3.0 Service Contract method will return 992 rows but not 993 rows. 50 column observable collection

Tags: wcf

When I try to run it with my test console application ... get error
An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to --http://d3w9501.americas.hpqcorp.net/SimpleWCF/SimpleWCF.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

when I try to run it from my silverlight application it pops up a login box.

Here is the serviceModel configuration in web.config

```
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="WSBigQuotaConfig" closeTimeout="00:01:00" openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00" allowCookies="false" bypassProxyOnLocal="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard" maxBufferSize="2097152" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2097152" messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" transferMode="Buffered" useDefaultWebProxy="true">
      <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2097152" maxArrayLength="2097152" maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384"/>
      <security mode="None">
        <transport clientCredentialType="None" proxyCredentialType="None" realm=""/>
        <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a whole bunch of limits in the readerQuotas,

2097152 / 990 = 2k per row and that doesn't seem a whole lot for 50 columns (40 char average).

So I think you just hit one of the limits.

Comment: Agreed, check your limits maxReceivedMessageSize

Comment: Here is the error message again.

An error occurred while receiving the HTTP response to http://d3w9501.americas.hpqcorp.net/SimpleWCF/SimpleWCF.svc. This could be due to the service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol. This could also be due to an HTTP request context being aborted by the server (possibly due to the service shutting down). See server logs for more details.

google this from the error ... in the exact word or phrase
service endpoint binding not using the HTTP protocol

Comment: on the client side the settings are:

maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647"

Silverlight and the test console app are both bugging out

Comment: it turns out that the issue was caused by missing configuration setting. 
Added the following attribute <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/> to the web.config in the section <serviceBehaviors>.

    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="SimpleWCFBehavior" >
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="True"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="True"/>
          <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

Comment: @Ferrel: you can post that as an answer to your own question.